# How to remove this plug to change the filter on this kitchen faucet?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet

I'm trying to replace the cartridge on this kitchen faucet, but I can't figure out how to get the little button to (presumably) get at the set screw. It is probably twenty years old. Closest I can match it to is this [Pfister Parisa Pullout Spray Kitchen Faucet](https://www.build.com/pfister-lg534-7/s1202678?uid=2877413&searchId=8GYEPxnQaJ). If [this](https://s1.img-b.com/build.com/mediabase/specifications/pfister/1202678/pfister-lg534-7-installation-sheet.pdf) is the installation manual, it just says "Carefully pry off Handle Button (24A) by using a small screwdriver or blade. Using a 3/32” Allen wrench, loosen Set Screw (24B) and remove Handle (24C)."

Is that little hot/cold button where the set screw is, and how do I remove it? It's not a rubber thing that you can just pull off with your fingernail like the current ones in the hardware store. It seems to be a hard plastic, judging by the gouges I've already left in it with a screwdriver. I can't get it to budge one way or another.

Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image: pfister faucet]

Comment: When they say small, they mean like pointy thin knife small.  Use old knife you are ready to throw out.

Comment: You can see the little hole (at the bottom)  where it is meant to go, which gives you a guide for its size.

Comment: It's often grunged up which makes it harder to remove, but it will come off.

Comment: You might be able to get by with a straight pin.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, yes, straight pin in that hole at the bottom was the answer.  It was all full of gunk was why it was stuck.

[image]